# Should I declare a double array with the GPU block number on the inner or outer dimension?

Tags: cuda

Should I declare a double array with the GPU block number on the inner or outer dimension?

E.g., should I do

```
int payload[LEN][BLOCKS];
```

or

```
int payload[BLOCKS][LEN];
```

where LEN is  a very large number.

I plan to have each block traverse the double array, holding the block dimension constant and iterating over the LEN dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're going to access the data in a block-oriented manner, you want to do the latter.  This is presumably because when you load the first element of the "len" dimension, you've already paid the cost for missing in the cache for the subsequent 7ish elements.  In the first option, there's probably sharing of cache lines between GPU blocks, but the sharing is relatively limited and not as low level.

Indeed, the below code reports that the second option requires 0.481 seconds to execute, and the first option requires 0.979 seconds.  **Arranging the data with the block on the outer dimension is about twice as performant.**

```
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>

#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

#define BLOCKS 80
#define LEN (1 << 20)

void CheckCudaErrorAux (const char *file, unsigned line, const char *statement, cudaError_t err) {
    if (err == cudaSuccess)
        return;
    std::cerr << statement<<" returned " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << "("<<err<< ") at "<<file<<":"<<line << std::endl;
    exit (1);
}
#define CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(value) CheckCudaErrorAux(__FILE__,__LINE__, #value, value)

struct Data1 {
    int payload[LEN][BLOCKS];
};

struct Data2 {
    int payload[BLOCKS][LEN];
};


__global__ void f1(Data1 * data1) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; ++i) {
        sum += data1->payload[i][blockIdx.x];
    }
    printf("block %i has f1 sum %i\n", blockIdx.x, sum);
}

__global__ void f2(Data2 * data2) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; ++i) {
        sum += data2->payload[blockIdx.x][i];
    }
    printf("block %i has f2 sum %i\n", blockIdx.x, sum);
}


int main() {

    Data1 * data1 = (Data1 *) malloc(sizeof(Data1));
    Data2 * data2 = (Data2 *) malloc(sizeof(Data2));;

    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; ++i) {
        for (int b = 0; b < BLOCKS; ++b) {
            data1->payload[i][b] = i * b;
            data2->payload[b][i] = i * b;
        }
    }

    Data1 * data1_on_gpu;
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMalloc(&data1_on_gpu, sizeof(Data1)));
    Data2 * data2_on_gpu;
    cudaMalloc(&data2_on_gpu, sizeof(Data2));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    cudaMemcpy(data1_on_gpu, data1, sizeof(Data1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(data2_on_gpu, data2, sizeof(Data1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceSynchronize());


    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    f1<<<80,1>>>(data1_on_gpu);
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> t2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    f2<<<80,1>>>(data2_on_gpu);
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> t3 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();


    std::chrono::duration<double> duration_1_to_2 = t2 - t1;
    std::chrono::duration<double> duration_2_to_3 = t3 - t2;
    duration_1_to_2.count();

    printf("timer for 1st took %.3lf\n", duration_1_to_2.count());
    printf("timer for 2nd took %.3lf\n", duration_2_to_3.count());

}
```

Comment: Indeed. But best just use a 1D array, instead of a 2D. The 2D array is fragmented, each of the pointers will be contiguous memory blocks, but the entire array will not be contiguous. If you use 1D arrays you can perhaps accelerate it even more using constant or texture memory (depending on your application)

Comment: niether one of these are efficient access patterns, and you never want to launch blocks consisting of one thread per block, if you are interested in performance on the GPU.  Furthermore, it's not clear you understand what the kernel launch config parameters are.  Unless you believe that your `f2` kernel needs precisely 1 byte of dynamically allocated shared memory (it doesn't), the `<<<80,1,1>>>` config doesn't make much sense.  In any event, `<<<80,1>>>`  or `<<<80,1,1>>>` is bad for performance.

Comment: The <<<80,1,1>>> was a typo -- fixed, thanks.  Semi-obviously my real application has many more than one thread per block.  This q&a was just to help me figure out how to layout one of my data structures.  In the real application, all of the threads within a block are reading from the same entry in `data[1/2]_on_gpu`, so I'm guessing that the additional threads would be inconsequential to answering this question.

Comment: In a way, I'm relieved that the performance difference is _only_ a factor of 2x.  To me, this means that the hardware has come a long way in making up for "bad" programming.  If the difference was significantly larger, then a "bad" choice here could have dominated my program's performance.  As it is, it probably doesn't matter much either way.